# Entity Framework add failed but sql script is okay

Tags: entity-framework-6, nservicebus, sql-server-profiler

I'm using Entity Framework to add new record, I can capture the insert SQL in SQL Server Profiler, but cannot find the new record in the database table.

When I copy the SQL captured and run it, I can get the record in the database table.

Question: why can I not find the new record in database table when adding it using Entity Framework?

Comment: Have you called SaveChanges()?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Just found the reason. It is not about entity framework but about Nservicebus. The Handler can roll back when cancelling debug even db Savechanges() is invoked.

Comment: Mark this as your answer.